# Proving that $\text{Span }(\vec{u},\vec{v},\vec{w})=\text{Span }(\vec{u},\vec{u}+\vec{v},\vec{u}+\vec{v}+\vec{w})$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following claim: $\DeclareMathOperator{\Span}{Span}$

> Let $V$ a vector space over the field $\mathbb{F}$.
> Need to prove that for each $\vec{u},\vec{v},\vec{w}\in V$ such that:$$\Span(\vec{u},\vec{v},\vec{w})=\Span(\vec{u},\vec{u}+\vec{v},\vec{u}+\vec{v}+\vec{w})$$

***My attempt:***

$Proof.$ Let $V$ a vector space over the field $\mathbb{F}$.

By definition we have:
$$\Span(\vec{u},\vec{v},\vec{w})=\{\beta_1\vec{u}+\beta_2\vec{v}+\beta_3\vec{w}:\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3\in \mathbb{F} \}$$
In addition, by $\Span(\vec{u},\vec{u}+\vec{v},\vec{u}+\vec{v}+\vec{w})$ definition we get:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\Span(\vec{u},\vec{u}+\vec{v},\vec{u}+\vec{v}+\vec{w}) &=\{\alpha_1\vec{u}+(\vec{u}+\vec{v})\alpha_2+(\vec{u}+\vec{v}+\vec{w})\alpha_3 :\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3 \in \mathbb{F} \} \\&= \{ \alpha_1\vec{u}+\alpha_2\vec{u}+\alpha_2\vec{v}+\alpha_3\vec{u}+\alpha_3\vec{u}+\alpha_3\vec{v}\} 
\\&=\{(\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3)\vec{u}+(\alpha_2+\alpha_3)\vec{v}+\alpha_3\vec{w}:\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3 \in \mathbb{F}  \}
\\&=\{\beta_1\vec{u}+\beta_2\vec{v}+\beta_3\vec{w}:\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3\in \mathbb{F}\}
\\&=\Span{(\vec{u},\vec{v},\vec{w})} \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \blacksquare
\end{split}
\end{equation}

---

I know that in order to show equality between two sets, I have to apply double inclusion.
However, any step in my proof has equality. Thus, I will be glad to see what you think about the proof, whether she is correct, or not, and if not to elaborate. Thanks!

Comment: Seems ok.................

Comment: Yes, but you could really show two inclusions, like done in [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2985086/given-the-vectors-u-v-w-in-a-vector-space-v-prove-that-spanu-v-w-spanu).

Comment: @DietrichBurde So you say that my proof is correct, however, there is more simple way to do that with two inclustions?

Comment: Not necessarily "more simple way", but rather "more clear way". For subspaces $U,W$ in $V$ to show equality, we show $U\subseteq W$ and $W\subseteq U$. This is very clean.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I got you. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest another proof, using matrices:$\DeclareMathOperator{\Span}{Span}$

It is obvious that $\vec u,\: \vec u+\vec v, \:\vec u+\vec v+\vec w$ belong to $\Span(\vec u, \vec v,\vec w)$ so that $\;\Span(\vec u,\vec u+\vec v, \vec u+\vec v+\vec w)\subseteq\Span(\vec u, \vec v,\vec w)$.

Therefore  all that has to be proved is the reverse inclusion. For this, observe we can write
$$\begin{bmatrix}\vec u\\\vec u+\vec v\\ \vec u+\vec v+\vec w\end{bmatrix}=
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0 \\1&1&0\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}}_{A}\begin{bmatrix}\vec u\\\vec v \\ \vec w\end{bmatrix}$$
The matrix $A$ is invertible, so we deduce
$$\begin{bmatrix}\vec u\\\vec v \\ \vec w\end{bmatrix}=A^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}\vec u\\\vec u+\vec v\\ \vec u+\vec v+\vec w\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\-1&1&0\\ 0&-1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\vec u\\\vec u+\vec v\\ \vec u+\vec v+\vec w \end{bmatrix},$$
which shows the reverse inclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Although nothing you have written is false, I do not think it is a great proof. The crux of the argument lies in this line, which you state without justification:
$$
\{(\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3)\vec{u}+(\alpha_2+\alpha_3)\vec{v}+\alpha_3\vec{w}:\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3 \in \mathbb{F}  \}
=\{\beta_1\vec{u}+\beta_2\vec{v}+\beta_3\vec{w}:\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3\in \mathbb{F}\}.
$$
Written as this is, it is clear that the left hand side is a subset of the right hand side. But for an element on the right hand side -- that is, essentially, a choice of $\beta_1, \beta_2, \beta_3$ -- it is not immediately clear that this is also an element of the left hand side -- that is, that we can choose $ \alpha_1, \alpha_2,\alpha_3$ so that $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + \alpha_3 = \beta_1$, and so on. This is the crux of the problem.

Bernard gives you a systematic approach for doing this, but you could also do it by hand (noting in this case that $\alpha_3 = \beta_3$, and continuing on from there).

Comment: So you say that I need to elaborate more about this move in the proof. I thought I should do that. If I write that we can always choose $\beta_1=\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3$ because this is a feature of the field when the field is closed to the + operation, is this would clarify my proof?

Comment: You're not choosing the $\beta_i$, though -- that would be the side I called "clear". You're choosing the $\alpha_i$.

Comment: You right sorry, but I can say that I am choosing:
$$\alpha_3=\beta_3,\alpha_2=\beta_2-\beta_3,\alpha_1=\beta_1-\beta_2$$
anything has done by the features of the field - closed to the + operation and every element has an inverse element.

Is that ok?

Comment: Yes, that works -- but I think explicitly referring to the field axioms is very excessive, just give the definitions of the $\alpha_i$ as you just did. Note that this is exactly what Bernard's answer does (check the coefficients of the last matrix in the answer)!

Comment: Oh, now I see thank you so much!